# How do I retrieve info of other users in Parse in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

ive been trying for a long time and i cant manage to find a solution

in the User class in parse, I added a new column and called it bio, im trying to retrieve that so i can set it inside the user's profile TextView, inside of android studio ofc

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String usersUsername = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> bioQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        bioQuery.whereEqualTo("username", usersUsername);
        bioQuery.getInBackground("bio", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    Log.i("info", "happy");
                } else {
                    Log.i("info", "sad");
                }
            }
        });
```

im getting the right username with the intent, im getting it from a listview that hold the users usernames

i always get "sad", i tried multiple other ways and regarding those other ways it
kept on telling me that there were no queries that match

please assist me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone looking for an answer to a question like mine, I managed to get a solution, which at second glance should've been obvious
I took Davi's advice and added to it what I needed

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String usersUsername = intent.getStringExtra("username");

ParseQuery<ParseUser> bioQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        bioQuery.whereEqualTo("username", usersUsername);
        bioQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    Log.i("info", "happy");
                    for(ParseUser user : objects){
                        Log.i("info", (String) user.get("bio"));
                        bio = (String) user.get("bio");
                    }
                    fullBioTextView.setText(bio);
                } else {
                    Log.i("info", "sad");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with findInBackground. It should be something like:

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String usersUsername = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> bioQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseUser);
        bioQuery.whereEqualTo("username", usersUsername);
        bioQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    Log.i("info", "happy");
                } else {
                    Log.i("info", "sad");
                }
            }
        });
```

You also need to make sure that you have access to the user. If it is not the current logged in user, you probably do not have access.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I do indeed want to the access the information of other users, why wouldn't I have access? lets say I want to display the emails of the other users in their "Contact Info" activity, would I not be able to do that?

Comment: Please disregard my last comment, I managed to get a solution thanks to your advice, much appreciated!

Comment: It is a security issue. If one user can get the e-mail of another user, imagine that anyone could use your api to retrieve the e-mail of all users. I wouldn't give access to a user to access the data of another user unless it is something that was specifically authorized by the user sharing their data.